# jespa : SSO using a "local logon"

Tags: java, single-sign-on, jespa

I'm currently evaluating jespa for Windows SSO support into our Web App. I'm facing the problem to make a try using my personal standalone workstation (win7) that is outside a Windows domain. Therefore, I've no Active Directory available to configure Jespa with. Does anybody know if this configuration is supported by jespa ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the Providing NTLM Services without Active Directory section in the Jespa Operator's Manual.

Note that IOPLEX Support will happily help you even if you have not purchased a license. If you have any further questions, just send them an email.

Comment: I know about this already but it does not say anything about SSO on a standalone machine. Do I need to write specific authenticating code? using which API?

Comment: You cannot do SSO without AD because you have to login to a machine joined to the domain. But when using the method cited, you will get a password dialog which will look to the web server like an SSO authentication. So it is a valid test in that you can be confident that it will work when you deliver it to the customer. Although if the domain, username and password configured matches the workstation name, username and password used to login to your stand-alone workstation, it might actually not ask you for a password. But again, this is an almost useless exercise.